# How can I create a pop up menu that has buttons in it on Android?

Tags: java, android, button, menu, popup

I have a few buttons on my screen, but having the screen to be as uncluttered as possible is important. Is there a way to click one button, have a pop up appear displaying the rest of the buttons, and select from those instead of just putting all the buttons on my app's front page?

Comment: what is wrong with a Dialog?

Comment: You can definitely achieve it with Dialog, or even PopupWindow. But it souunds Sounds a bit like a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) to me. Which is already pre-built

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

example (using `ListView` to list all the choices):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Make your choice");

ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Choice 1", "Choice 2" };
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

builder.setView(modeList);
final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

dialog.show();
```

Another example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Basically, you are creating a Dialogue and inserting a view into it